# Reputation not updating properly

Tags: support, reputation

I currently see a reputation of 31 in my profile with four badges. So far I have answered two questions: One received neither up-, nor down-vote but the other one received 5 up-votes and was accepted as an answer.

Yesterday - before my answer got accepted and once more up-voted (from 4 to 5), my reputation was already 31, and now, after an accepted answer and an update it's still 31?

Apparently my answer got accepted about 9 hours ago - is it possible, that my reputation has not been updated yet?

In my reputation-tracker the accepted & again up-voted answer does not even appear, the last recorded reputation change is from May 29.

**EDIT**

I just noticed, that if each up-vote is +10 and I got 5 up-votes, then in fact two up-votes are missing? Because 5 * 10 = 50 + rep for getting accepted as an answer.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On all SE sites, reputation by casting a vote applies immediately. But it'll take some time before you see the changes caused by deleting a post or undoing vote up or vote down. As far as I know (and have experience) there is nothing wrong with the system. But about why you didn't receive those, I've got a theory! if you check your profile now it indicates you didn't answer that question, that's because your answer is now considered as "community wiki". In fact any answer that has more than 10 edits is considered as community wiki. which means you won't get any benefit from vote-up, and you won't receive penalty for vote-downs. Now If I'm not wrong, your answer had 3 votes before your 10 edits, so you received reputation for it, but other two votes and the accept happened when you were not owner of that answer. And the reason why you could see the answer with 5 votes in your profile should be the fact that these kind of updates take some time to apply. I'm not sure if I could explain it good enough, ask me if you still have any problems.

Comment: Oh I think I get it - what a bummer :(. I had to edit the answer a (felt) hundred times - because the question was initially unclear (I think it was edited later on by the OP) and the OP always requested additional infos in the comments -_- ...

Comment: @Zainodis Gajet is correct about the votes not counting towards your reputation due to community wiki.  This doesn't change the fact it's a great answer!  I'm sure more reputation will head your way.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Thanks for the nice comment, really appreciated :)

Comment: @Zainodis For the record: this is one of the reasons to bring discussions into chat. Discuss things at length with the person asking for more information, talk about whatever you want and resolve their further questions, then go back and do a single large edit to your post containing all the information relevant to the solution (or a couple of large edits along the way - up to you).

Comment: @JonathanHobbs I guess you're right, however how you tell that person: Meet me in chat (As I can't drop him a message, except in the comments)? The whole thing stretched over days and I am not always on, neither was the OP I guess. And I really wanted to help him. In the end I concluded it's all right, at least he got his help and can move on with the game he's working on and I guess that's the whole point of it :)

Comment: @Zainodis Go to chat and create a room, then link to it.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs thanks for the hint, I'll keep it in mind for the future.